# Opening install.txt when installing Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux

I know this may sound sily but I don't how to open install.txt. I tried 'w3m install.txt' and '_w3m install.txt' but still don't open. Can someone specify the code to do this?

Comment: `.txt` files are openend with a text editor: try `nano install.txt`. `w3m` is a web browser, try `w3m https://wiki.archlinux.org`.

Comment: thank you for help. I was told I can open install.txt with w3m

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use any of the following methods to view the installer

- `less install.txt`
- `more install.txt`
- `vi install.txt`

Or if you have access to the internet from within the installer you can also switch to a different tty `<ALT>+<F2-F6>` and launch `elinks http://wiki.archlinux.org/` (`elinks` is terminal web-browser). Then you can reference the wiki articles while keeping your installation on tty1 (`<ALT>+<F1>`).

The installation media also has `irssi` (irc client) preloaded on it. Feel free to join #archlinux on freenode.net for live support during the installation.

If you want keep irc open on tty3 browser one tty2, and installation on tty1.

Comment: Upvoted, but `vi install.txt`? Really? That could be misconstrued as cruel and inhuman...

Comment: I couldn't agree with you any more. I figured the user would be satisfied with `less install.txt` the first one and not even worry about trying the other two. But if he gets to `vi install.txt` he'll see why it's listed last.

Comment: @cinelli great! I've learned a lot of useful things from you answer .